# Angular UI Bootstrap modal dialog in $http interceptor hangs the browser

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-http

I'm trying to implement lazy authorization which will bring in the login dialog only when user triggers call to API requiring authentication. I'm using bootstrap [ui.bootstrap.modal](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal) (and [ui.bootstrap.alert](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/alert) within the modal). The problem is that these directives explicitly specify following `teamplateUrl`'s:

- template/modal/backdrop.html (in `modal.js` [here](https://github.com/2ooom/bootstrap/blob/0.11.2/src/modal/modal.js#L64))
- template/modal/window.html (in `modal.js` [here](https://github.com/2ooom/bootstrap/blob/0.11.2/src/modal/modal.js#L87))
- template/alert/alert.html (in `alert.js` [here](https://github.com/2ooom/bootstrap/blob/0.11.2/src/alert/alert.js#L11))

like this:

```
.directive('modalBackdrop', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'template/modal/backdrop.html',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      /* ... */
    }
  };
}])
```

And every time I'm calling `$modal.open()` and ui-bootstrap builds DOM for new modal window, angular tries to resolve those urls via `$http` service even though the templates are already loaded either by [`$templateCache.put`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) method or by adding a `<script>` tag.
This is basically causing infinite recursion in my interceptor which tries to bring in login dialog in `request` overload for the urls above.

Here is simplified version of my interceptor:

```
.config(['$provide', '$httpProvider', function($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.factory('testInterceptor', ['$injector', function($injector) {
        return {
        'request': function(config) {

            var auth = $injector.get('authService');
            var modal = $injector.get('$modal');
            if (!auth.LoggedIn) {
              var loginModal = modal.open({
                  template: 'Login screen <alert type="warning">some message</alert>',
              });
              return loginModal.result;
            }
            return config;
          }
}}]);
```

Working demo is [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WnhW99dbP9c9PlQ9Yr2O)

Can anyone advise the approach which will not involve hard-coding of the templateUrls used in `ui.bootstrap.modal` and `ui.bootstrap.alert`?

I've also reported this as an [issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2926)  on github.

Comment: How come you're using $injector instead of just passing those things in as dependencies? i.e. `$injector.get('$modal')`

Comment: this won't work supposedly because interceptor is being registered in `config` section which supports only providers injection (see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to workaround this is to not enforce authentication on requests to any URL that begins with `template/`. Like so:

```
      $provide.factory('testIntercepter', ['$q', '$injector',
        function($q, $injector) {
          return {
            'request': function(config) {
              if (config.url.indexOf('template/') == 0) {
                log('ignoring ' + config.url);
                return config;
              }

              log(config.method + ' ' + config.url);
              var auth = $injector.get('authService');
              if (!auth.LoggedIn) {
                return auth.Login();
              }
              return config;
            },
          }
        }
      ]);
```

Example Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kADmHkfHiyKW8kd7aNep?p=preview

---

A more sophisticated option might be to check the `$templateCache` if it contains the URL requested, and skip authentication for those cases:

```
      $provide.factory('testIntercepter', ['$q', '$injector', '$templateCache',
        function($q, $injector, $templateCache) {
          return {
            'request': function(config) {
              if ($templateCache.get(config.url)) {
                log('in $templateCache ' + config.url);
                return config;
              }

              log(config.method + ' ' + config.url);
              var auth = $injector.get('authService');
              if (!auth.LoggedIn) {
                return auth.Login();
              }
              return config;
            },
          }
        }
      ]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/RfkTmGinobxIWmg1BrMJ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @sirhc, I would do both checks. Good point about `$templateCache`!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `templateUrl`. Check this code out (also deals with authorization). I use inline modal template. This is part of bigger script that opens modal and allows routing within open modal dialog, so that one does not have to close modal when you want to perform series of actions in a modal dialog.

```
$modal.open({
     template: "<div data-ng-include='templateUrl'></div>",
     controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {

     $modalInstance.opened
         .then(function () {
             if (startRouteName != "unauthorized") {
                 var requiredAuthorizations = 
                        $scope.getRequiredPermissions(startRouteName);
                 if (requiredAuthorizations) {
                     $scope.hasAnyPermission(requiredAuthorizations)
                         .then(function (result) {
                             if (!result) {
                                 startRouteName = "unauthorized";
                             }
                             afterModalOpened($scope);
                     });
                 } else {
                     afterModalOpened($scope);
                 }
             } else {
                 afterModalOpened($scope);
             }
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: I'm also using inline `template` in my [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/WnhW99dbP9c9PlQ9Yr2O) the problem is that angular-ui itself is using `templateUrl`, which causes my itercepter to loop